# Интеграционный-тест Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, rest

Привет, нужна помощь!

Учу Java вечерами второй месяц, хочу научиться, понять и работать.

Пишу тестовое задание: REST-бекэнд для игры крестики нолики на maven+SpringBoot.

Текущая цель : сделать интеграционный-тест  имитирующий игру 2х игроков.
(как я это понимаю тест который будет дергать POST/GET запросами мой REST-API и сравнивать полученные ответы с ожидаемыми результатами)

и тут я влип:
многое читал, понял не всё, иду по этому(с ~11 минуты):
https://youtu.be/UjGTCCkKnvs?t=10m45s

```
ControllerIT.java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Controller.class) //1
@WebIntegrationTest                               //2
public class ControllerIT {
public void ControllersampleIT(){
}
}
```

Вот эти 1 и 2 аннотации показывают ошибку. В IDEA жму на них `Alt+Enter`->Add maven dependency.. добавляю.
И сразу отваливается строка в Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); //вот эта
    }
}
```

Исходники

скачать zip или `git clone`
https://github.com/jiraff537/tic-tac-toe-RESTfulWebService.git

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, исправил.

Comment: что такое "отваливается строка"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видео устарело. Надо использовать другие аннотации. Вот так надо оформить свой тест.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ControllerIT {

    @Test
    public void ControllersampleIT() {
        System.out.println("16-54");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Помогло, спасибо теперь другая проблема "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"и в другом месте создам ещё один вопрос...